# Using a config block at the top of the file throws error

Tags: sinatra

I'm trying to set a connection to the database (using Sequel) before the model appears.  Well it must be that way but am getting an error

```
undefined method `configure' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Here is the code, I don't see anything wrong with setting up the constants there so perhaps it is either something related to the configure block or the config.ru.

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sequel'
require 'slim'
require 'sass'
require 'sinatra/flash'
require './sinatra/auth'

configure :development do
  password = ENV["PGPASSWORD"]
  DB = Sequel.postgres('development', user: 'postgres', password: password, host: 'localhost')
end

configure :production do
  DB = Sequel.connect(ENV['DATABASE_URL'])
end
```

Here is the rack file.  I tried to do the connect statement in there but failed (so far)

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require './main'
require './song'
require 'sequel'

map('/songs') { run SongController }
map('/') { run Website}
```

Not understanding why the configure block will not work.

Edit: I'm guessing because the call to the SongController is in config.ru, the connect statements need to be in there as well. 
Edit: And further along , since this is a modular app, a config.yml is probably my best option.

Comment: I dropped the `configure do` block and went `if and elsif`  ;) , it works but I'm leaving the post because I do not understand why the` configure do` throws an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `sinatra/base`. That means you'll have to use a subclass:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sequel'
require 'slim'
require 'sass'
require 'sinatra/flash'
require './sinatra/auth'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  configure :development do
    password = ENV["PGPASSWORD"]
    DB = Sequel.postgres('development', user: 'postgres', password: password, host: 'localhost')
  end

  configure :production do
    DB = Sequel.connect(ENV['DATABASE_URL'])
  end

  run! if app_file == $0 
end
```

NB: You can just use `require sinatra` and all the magic without using subclasses will be abailable. Or, if you need a modular app, use `Sinatra::Application` and you will have all the magic included. See sinatra's readme for full coverage on the differences.

Comment: This was a tutorial and went from a classic to a modular for demonstration purposes.  The tutorial though uses datamapper, which behaves differently for connection then Sequel (the ORM I used). I'll read up.  I didn't realize the run! was needed in the sublcass.

Comment: If you use modular apps I'd use a config.ru. There you can bundle more apps together. Then fire up a server like puma which reads the config.ru. Of course you can also just leave everything in one file. Alwayxs depends on what you prefer and what purpose your file has. Read the sinatra up and running book. It's really useful.